# DragGestureRecognizer без удержания на элементе

Tags: c#, android, maui

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы перетаскивание элемента срабатывало без удержания пальца на элементе, просто при обычном нажатии. То есть я просто прикоснулся к элементу и сразу начал его переносить.

Comment: непонятно, как можно перетаскивать не перетаскивая